# is there any solution for login query builder in laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, controller

none result appears

how can i solve this problem, i used this code but none result appears, just stay on the login page, it has to be redirecting to the homepage

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');

Mengambil kredensial user dari database berdasarkan email
        $user = DB::table('users')
            ->where('email', $email)
            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
            ->first();

if ($user && Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {
Jika kredensial cocok, maka login berhasil
Lakukan sesuatu setelah login berhasil
return redirect()->route('home');
else {
Jika kredensial tidak cocok, redirect dengan pesan error
return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors(['email' => 'Invalid email or password']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed  your code quoting and reformatted your code, there are sentences like `Mengambil kredensial user dari database berdasarkan email`, are those comments in your code? (Feed free to edit the question)

Comment: Maybe validation fails, do you show validation errors in your view?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
        $user = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();
        if ($user && $user->is_deleted) {
            return redirect('/')->with('error','You are no longer active user  !!');
        }
        if(!$user){
            return redirect('/')->with('error','Please Enter Valid User Email or Password');

        }
     $remember=$request->remember??'';
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials,$remember)) {
           
            return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
        }
        // Authentication failed
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => __('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/')->with('success','You are logged out!!');
    }
```

This May help this my cusom login and logout code...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).